# Azure pipeline CLI task with acr purge getting failed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

Getting below error

> ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
> ERROR: 'NoneType' object is not callable
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke

```
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: ACR_cleanup
    jobs:
      - job: acr_cleanup
        steps:
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: Azure CLI
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: Cleanup_SC
              scriptType: bash
              scriptLocation: inlineScript
              inlineScript: |
                az --version
                az account show
                az acr run --cmd "acr purge --filter 'my-image:.*' --ago 30d --untagged" --registry <> /dev/null
```

Changed pipeline to variable but same error

```
variables:
- name: purge_cmd
  value: acr purge --filter 'image:.*' --ago 30d --untagged --dry-run

#Resource pool to use
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: ACR_cleanup
    jobs:
      - job: acr_cleanup
        steps:
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: Azure CLI
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: Cleanup_SC
              scriptType: bash
              scriptLocation: inlineScript
              inlineScript: |
                az --version
                az account show
                az acr run --cmd "$(purge_cmd)" --registry <> /dev/null
```

Tried in local PowerShell cmd with azure cli getting a proper response for below command

```
 $PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'image:.*' --ago 30d --untagged --dry-run"                                                                                                                                                  
 az acr run --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" --registry <registry> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

az cli version 2.26.1 only supports the same. The current latest image cli version is 2.26.0